# Validating generated number input with Bootstrap FormValidation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I've been struggling to get this field validation to work. I'm using the JS validation for bootstrap from http://formvalidation.io/ and I've examined http://formvalidation.io/settings/ but nothing I've tried is working.

**The field needs to validate a number input on a dynamically generated field using Razer C#, and the form is built to submit multiple models, therefore my name attribute is `values[@i].Rating` for each element that is generated, where `i` is an integer that is incremented in a loop.**

The validation must make sure the client enters a number between 1 and 4 (inclusive), and if it is not a number between 1 and 4, it must show an error message such as "Please enter a number between 1 and 4". Here is my code, I first tried it with HTML attributes:

```
<input style="text-align: center" type="number" data-fv-between-min="1" data-fv-between-max="4" data-fv-between-inclusive="true" data-fv-between-message="Please enter a rating between 1 and 4" name="values[@i].Rating" class="form-control" />
```

but this didn't work, so I tried the javascript route with:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newTSRForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
            selector: '[type="number"]',
            input: {
                validators: {
                    between: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 4,
                        message: 'Please enter a value between 1 and 4'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

but my syntax is probably wrong or my thinking is incorrect. I also tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#newTSRForm').formValidation({
        framework: 'bootstrap',
        fields: {
            'values[]': {
                validators: {
                    between: {
                        min: 1,
                        max: 4,
                        message: 'Please enter a value between 1 and 4'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
```

But this doesn't work either. I have made sure my set up is correct so the problem is simply syntax or plausability. Can anybody advise?

Answer (score 1):

¿ Did you look at http://formvalidation.io/examples/validating-field-special-name/ ?
I think you have to add every single field with the AddField method of the Plugin.. [Adding dynamic field](http://formvalidation.io/examples/adding-dynamic-field/)